# Design Pattern for Custom Events in .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

What is the proper design pattern for custom events in .NET (VB or C#).

Please note I am refering to *custom events*, where in you override the AddHandler, RemoveHander, and RaiseEvent methods.

Comment: There isn't a design pattern. There's interface semantics: `RemoveHandler` should be able to remove things added with `AddHandler`, neither should complain if asked to do the same thing twice in succession. But apart from that you can do whatever you want - the point is to override the behaviour, after all.

Comment: By "Design Pattern" I mean "the pattern that most people use when designing X to ensure correct semantics and thread safety". What definition were you thinking of?

Comment: I don't think custom events have necessitated their own patterns because the customizations aren't very widely used or required. 

1. Why do you need to override this basic functionality?
2. "The" proper design pattern? A pattern is there to give you a meaningful way to discuss what you're doing - it isn't a guide for how to construct a solution. If you're asking for the right pattern for your needs without providing any information about what those needs are, you're already on the wrong foot.

Answer (score -1):

1- Best practices for creating events is to do it the Microsoft's way, that is: the delegate takes 2 parameters, the first is the sender (who raises the event?) of type object, and arguments (additional information about the event) of type EventArgs or any derived type. Also don't return a value (void) from the event, and put all data you need in the 2nd argument. Check the [example in this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx).

2- Thread safety is another story, but you can start from these tips (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)):

> In general, avoid locking on a public
>   type, or instances beyond your code's
>   control. The common constructs lock
>   (this), lock (typeof (MyType)), and
>   lock ("myLock") violate this
>   guideline:
>
> ```
> * lock (this) is a problem if the instance can be accessed publicly.
>
> * lock (typeof (MyType)) is a problem if MyType is publicly accessible.
>
> * lock(“myLock”) is a problem because any other code in the process using the same string, will share the same lock.
> ```
>
> Best practice is to define a private
>   object to lock on, or a private static
>   object variable to protect data common
>   to all instances.
>
> example:

```
Object thisLock = new Object(); 
lock(thisLock) 
{
   // Critical code section. 
}
```